# Find a cell of text that matches an array with wildcards

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a function that compares the string in a cell with an array of strings with wildcards. For example, `\my\path\a` in A1 will be matched by `\my\path\?` or `\my\*\a`

So far, I'm using `match` function, is their something like

```
match(A1, {"\my\path\?", "\my\*\a"}, 0}
```

can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=MATCH( {"\my\path\?","\my\*\a"},A1,0)
```

entered as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) will return an array containing a result for each entry in the array: `#N/A` for no match, 1 for match.

---

Where to go from there depends on what result you want:

To count the number of matching patterns (enter as an array formula):

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH( {"\my\path\?","\my\*\a"},A1,0),0))
```

To detect if *any* pattern matches, as `TRUE` or `FALSE` (enter as an array formula):

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH( {"\my\path\?","\my\*\a"},A1,0),0))>0
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the array formula. Can you please elaborate more? If in a cell the content is \my\path\x or \my\xx\a, then when I apply this function in another cell, it should produce 1

Comment: Use the formula `=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH( {"\my\path\?","\my\*\a"},A1,0),0))` (entered as an array formula: that is when you finish typing it in press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` all together, rather than just `Enter`).  This returns the number of patterns in the formula that match the value of `A1`.  Eg if `A1` = `\my\path\x` or `\my\xx\a` it returns `1`.  If `A1` = `\my\path\a` it returns `2` because that string matches _both_ patterns.